# Mod-rewrite multilanguage

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

There are some html files on server with different languages:

```
company.html
index.html
en_company.html
en_index.html
```

I want to make redirect like this:

```
www.site.com/ > www.site.com/index.html
www.site.com/company/ > www.site.com/company.html

www.site.com/en/ > www.site.com/en_index.html
www.site.com/en/company/ > www.site.com/en_company.html
```

Why doesn't it work?

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/$ $1.php [L,NC,NE,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/en/]*)/$ en_$1.php [L,NC,NE,QSA]
```

Thanks!

Comment: Your rule is adding a `.php` extension but your question wants them to route to `.html`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put this code in your htaccess (which has to be in root folder)

```
Options -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# don't touch existing files/folders
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# rewrite /lang/ to /lang_index.html
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})/$ $1_index.html [L]

# rewrite /lang/page/ to /lang_page.html
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1_$2\.html -f
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})/([^/]+)/$ $1_$2.html [L]

# rewrite /page/ to /page.html
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.html -f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1.html [L]
```